# jQuery not working on iPad

Tags: jquery, forms, ipad, counter

I have a rather anoying problem. I am making a contest in which the score is being kept. There are 5 questions. It contains a form with radio buttons. jQuery checks which radio button is selected and counts a variable everytime a correct answer is given. The following jQuery code has been written:

```
var i = 0;
var correctQuestions = 0;

function readValue(){

        var antwoordVraag1 = $('input[name=q1]:checked', '#comp').val();
        var antwoordVraag2 = $('input[name=q2]:checked', '#comp').val();
        var antwoordVraag3 = $('input[name=q3]:checked', '#comp').val();
        var antwoordVraag4 = $('input[name=q4]:checked', '#comp').val();
        var antwoordVraag5 = $('input[name=q5]:checked', '#comp').val();

        if (i === 0){
            $('.question-wrapper-1').fadeOut("slow", function(){
                $('.question-wrapper-2').fadeIn("slow");
            });
            i++;
            $('.progress-radio-btn-1').attr('src','common/img/question-btn.png');
            $('.progress-radio-btn-2').attr('src','common/img/question-btn-active.png');
            if(antwoordVraag1 == 1){
                correctQuestions++;
            }
            console.log('Vragen goed = '+correctQuestions);
        }

        else if (i === 1){
            $('.question-wrapper-2').fadeOut("slow", function(){
                $('.question-wrapper-3').fadeIn("slow");
            });
            i++;
            $('.progress-radio-btn-2').attr('src','common/img/question-btn.png');
            $('.progress-radio-btn-3').attr('src','common/img/question-btn-active.png');
            if(antwoordVraag2 == 1){
                correctQuestions++;
            }
            console.log('Vragen goed = '+correctQuestions);
        }

        else if (i === 2){
            $('.question-wrapper-3').fadeOut("slow", function(){
                $('.question-wrapper-4').fadeIn("slow");
            });
            i++;
            $('.progress-radio-btn-3').attr('src','common/img/question-btn.png');
            $('.progress-radio-btn-4').attr('src','common/img/question-btn-active.png');
            if(antwoordVraag3 == 2){
                correctQuestions++;
            }
            console.log('Vragen goed = '+correctQuestions);
        }

        else if (i === 3){
            $('.question-wrapper-4').fadeOut("slow", function(){
                $('.question-wrapper-5').fadeIn("slow");
            });
            i++;
            $('.progress-radio-btn-4').attr('src','common/img/question-btn.png');
            $('.progress-radio-btn-5').attr('src','common/img/question-btn-active.png');
            if(antwoordVraag4 == 3){
                correctQuestions++;
            }
            console.log('Vragen goed = '+correctQuestions);
        }

        else if (i === 4){
            $('#question-btn').fadeOut(),500;
            $('.progress-radio').fadeOut(),500;
            $('.question-wrapper-5').fadeOut("slow", function(){
                $('.final-wrapper').fadeIn("slow");
            });
            if(antwoordVraag5 == 3){
                correctQuestions++;
            }
            console.log('Vragen goed = '+correctQuestions);
        }

        else{
            alert('Something went wrong...');
            alert(i);
        }

}
```

This works just fine on desktop. However, when I test it on the iPad, the alertbox gives an "i" value of 86. I don't know how to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the entire Javascript code? Any other code using variable i?

Comment: No other code is using the variable. But I seem to have solved it. I added " i = 0 " to the else statement